# Creación de websocket php en Cpanel

Tags: php, apache, socket, cpanel

tengo una duda espero me puedan ayudar, pasa que soy nuevo en la creación de websocket y no tengo la menor idea de como realizarlo, he estado viendo varios ejemplos y quiero hacer uno en PHP, hay un ejemplo que estoy usando y es el siguiente:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0); // disable timeout
ob_implicit_flush(); // disable output caching 

// Settings    
$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 9000;

/*
    function socket_create ( int $domain , int $type , int $protocol )
    $domain can be AF_INET, AF_INET6 for IPV6 , AF_UNIX for Local communication protocol
    $protocol can be SOL_TCP, SOL_UDP  (TCP/UDP)
    @returns true on success
*/

if (($socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "Couldn't create socket".socket_strerror(socket_last_error())."\n";
}


/*
    socket_bind ( resource $socket , string $address [, int $port = 0 ] )
    Bind socket to listen to address and port
*/

if (socket_bind($socket, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "Bind Error ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) ."\n";
}

if (socket_listen($socket, 5) === false) {
    echo "Listen Failed ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
}

do {
    if (($msgsock = socket_accept($socket)) === false) {
        echo "Error: socket_accept: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
        break;
    }

    /* Send Welcome message. */
    $msg = "\nPHP Websocket \n";

    // Listen to user input
    do {
        if (false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ))) {
            echo "socket read error: ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error($msgsock)) . "\n";
            break 2;
        }
        if (!$buf = trim($buf)) {
            continue;
        }

        // Reply to user with their message
        $talkback = "PHP: You said '$buf'.\n";
        socket_write($msgsock, $talkback, strlen($talkback));
        // Print message in terminal
        echo "$buf\n";
        
    } while (true);
    socket_close($msgsock);
} while (true);

socket_close($socket);
```

?>

Tengo una idea vaga de que esta pasando, entiendo que el socket es para comunicación bidireccional tal como lo usan los chats, pero la duda que tengo en como saber como activarla (si puedo usar esa palabra) en un cpanel y por ejemplo si quiero probar en algún sitio como https://www.piesocket.com/websocket-tester#, como se cual es mi wss://dominio.com:9000, (quiero que sean en el puerto 9000), no entiendo como se forma en wss.

Comment: Si estas en un servidor compartido con cpanel es probable que usen un firewall y que solo abran los puertos estrictamente necesarios para cpanel y poca cosa más.  Asegúrate que te abren el puerto que quieras usar en tu caso antes de desesperarte viendo que no funciona por ese motivo.

Comment: Y quizás, si lo dejas así: `$address = '127.0.0.1';` tan solo quedará a la escucha en esa IP, siendo imposible alcanzarla desde fuera.  Quizás deberías investigar cual es tu IP pública de tu dominio y ponerla en esa variable para que tu ws sea público también (eso si antes te han abierto el puerto o no tienen restricciones de puertos, claro)

Comment: Ok, creo que entiendo, entonces tendría que ver si el puerto que quiero usar (9000) esta abierto, entonces digamos que el archivo que estoy usando de ejemplo esta en https://dominio.com/files_test/talkdesk/socket1/, mi WSS sería un equivalente a wss://dominio.com:9000/files_test/talkdesk/socket1/???? o me estoy equivocando?

Comment: Diria que la url la pones bien, si esa carpeta **files_test** esta dentro de tu **/home/usuario/public_html**

Comment: Si, exacto, así esta la estructura básicamente, por ello me surgió la duda de como seria el WSS siendo igual a la estructura de la URL solo que en ves de HTTPS pongo WSS://host:port/files_test_talkdesk/socket1, no?

Comment: eso ya ni idea, nunca he usado websockets, pero entiendo que sí, que deberia funcionar aunque el protocolo cambie de http/https a wss